# Batch read file content into variable

Tags: batch-file

I'm in need to read a config file and if i get a line starting with exactly "config=" i have to write what's on the right of the '=' into a variable to use it later on the script. I'm tryng something like this but i'm quite lost atm

```
for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %G in (config.properties) do if "%G%" == "config" set @usedConfig=%H
```

Comment: You could try using `FindStr` to isolate the line first: `For /F "Tokens=1*Delims==" %%A In ('FindStr /IB "config=" "config.properties"')Do Set "Config=%%B"`. If the line exists, the variable `%Config%` should hold the value you require.

Comment: You are referencing the `FOR` variable incorrectly. It should be `%G`